# Oracle 11g - Creating a side by side comparison of table comlumn data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query where I need to extract data in a regular table and put two rows of data into a single row.
    I have rows that consist of

```
StudentID  AUDIT_ACTN     Audit_Date .....  
aaa          A             01/01/2010  
aaa          A             03/04/2011      
aaa          A             02/02/2013  
aaa          D             09/10/2010  
aaa          D             05/06/2011  
aaa          D             06/07/2013  
aaa          A             11/12/2014~
bbb          A             01/01/2010  
bbb          A             03/04/2011      
bbb          A             02/02/2013  
bbb          D             09/10/2010  
bbb          D             05/06/2011  
bbb          D             06/07/2013  
bbb          A             11/12/2014~
```

I want output like this

```
StudentID  AUDIT_ACTN   Audit_Date  StudentID  AUDIT_ACTN   Audit_Date  
aaa          A          01/01/2010    aaa          D         09/10/2010  
aaa          A          03/04/2011    aaa          D         05/06/2011  
aaa          A          02/02/2013    aaa          D         06/07/2013  
aaa          A         11/12/2014      NULL       NULL        NULL  
bbb          A          01/01/2010    bbb          D         09/10/2010  
bbb          A          03/04/2011    bbb          D         05/06/2011  
bbb          A          02/02/2013    bbb          D         06/07/2013  
bbb          A         11/12/2014      NULL       NULL        NULL
```

The A & D data rows are related, a= add the something to the record and d = delete something from the record  (something is an indicator).  These is logical in that you must add something before you delete it and you cannot add it twice, without deleting it first.

My current script is probably going down the wrong track but here goes;

```
    select a.StudentId,a.Audit_Date,a.AUDIT_ACTN,d.StudentId,Audit_Date,d.AUDIT_ACTN,
from table a
join
(select *
   from
    (Select StudentId, Audit_Date,AUDIT_ACTN
        from table b
        Where b.AUDIT_ACTN='D' 
        order by Audit_Date
    )
    where rownum=1
    ) d on a.StudentId = d.StudentId
and a.AUDIT_ACTN='A'
and Select * from (Select Audit_Date 
Order by a.StudentId, a.Audit_Date
```

I know this is wrong but where do I go from here.  If anyone can help and point me in the right direction. It would be appreciated.

My current attempts bring me zero rows, when I take out the rownum it brings me a x join returning 12 rows in this case.
thanks 
Roger

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow how you are figuring out which A row maps to which D row.  All the rows in your sample relate to the same `StudentID`.  Are you just relating them by saying that the first D (ordered by the `audit_date`) for a particular student necessarily matches up with the first A (again ordered by the `audit_date`)?  That seems unlikely in the scenario you've constructed here-- presumably, I may delete values in a different order than I added them or delete some values and not others.

Comment: Thanks for your thought.  Rows are not deleted.  This is an audit table where action in the system are recorded.  You are correct - there is no hard link but a logical link only.  e.g. aaa has an indicator assigned to them on a date, then has it removed after on another date. Then re-added again on a date.  So you cannot add an indicator to the person without a delete transaction (unless its the first time the indicator is added).  You cannot delete an indicator without an add transaction.  The dates in the sample reflect this (i hope).  I hope this explains a little more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need aggregate function like below

```
    select 
         A.StudentId,A.Audit_Date,A.AUDIT_ACTN,
         D.StudentId,D.Audit_Date,D.AUDIT_ACTN
    from 
    (Select StudentId, Audit_Date,AUDIT_ACTN,ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER (PARTITION BY StudentId order by audit_date) rn
            from table b
            Where b.AUDIT_ACTN='D'
    ) D
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (Select StudentId, Audit_Date,AUDIT_ACTN,ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER (PARTITION BY StudentId order by audit_date) rn
            from table b
            Where b.AUDIT_ACTN='A'
    ) A
    on A.rn = D.rn and A.StudentId = B.StudentId
```

I hope this will work

Comment: Thanks, this works beautifully for 1 student Id but not for multiple student IDs, there need to be a studentid match as well..  Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Thanks, close but no cigar.  This fails at the point where the student Id and rownnum combinations do not match, i get different studentIDs on a single row.  I have tried to sort table a, d by the studentid, audit_date but that does work.  I was think a partition (?) might work?

Comment: Sorry,  I missed your a.studentid = b.studentid; but that still gives me mismatched student ids on the same row.

Comment: This is more the liking which gives the most desired result; instead of rownum, insert - row_number() over (order by studentId)